# Rescheduling same method in Cocos2d-x 3.1

Tags: cocos2d-x, scheduler, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have the following code in Cocos2d-x v3.1:

```
void Board::createNewRandomBottomRow()
{
    //eventHappening is a variable modified in other parts of the code
    //I don't want that while eventHappening is true, this method does anything
    if ( eventHappening ) {
         this -> scheduleOnce( SEL_SCHEDULE( &Board::createNewRandomBottomRow ), 0.3f );
    }
    else
    {
        //actual logic
    } 
 }
```

However, I check with the debugger that the method is not being rescheduled. Isn't it possible to reschedule a method from inside the same method?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did the same again in another simpler scenario, and the rescheduling works fine, so I guess I messed up in the logic in another part of the code.

So just to sum up: rescheduling a method from inside the method itself works fine.